# What is the time-complexity of the pseudo-inverse in pytorch (i.e. torch.pinverse)?

Tags: python, neural-network, time-complexity, pytorch

Let's say I have a matrix `X` with `n, m == X.shape` in **PyTorch**.
What is the time complexity of calculating the pseudo-inverse with `torch.pinverse`?

In other words, what is the time complexity of

```
X_p = torch.pinverse(X)
```

?

Here is the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=inverse#torch.pinverse)

Comment: [This looks right](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24060/complexity-of-finding-the-pseudoinverse-matrix)

Comment: @EdekiOkoh I'm not sure - the PyTorch library implements it using SVD, which is more computationally expensive than matrix multiplication.

Comment: I think your right actually. Looking at your articles it appears to be the the correct answer. I up-voted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PyTorch documentation states that pinverse [is calculated using SVD](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.pinverse) (singular value decomposition). The complexity of SVD is `O(n m^2)`, where `m` is the larger dimension of the matrix and `n` the smaller. Thus this is the complexity.

For more info, check out these pages on wikipedia:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Singular_value_decomposition_(SVD)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra

Comment: According to the second link you reference it is `O(max(m,n)^2 * min(m,n))`, maybe it would be good to make this clarification in your answer.

Comment: @patapouf_ai you can edit the answer, too if you think more information would be helpful.

Comment: Actually, it is O(n^2 . m) for m > n (as the second row says).

Answer (score 4):

As the privious answer correctly mentioned, it is `O(n m^2)`, but `n` is the larger dimension, not `m` (here is where the previous answer goes wrong).

TLDR: **it is linear in the larger dimension and quadratic in the smaller dimension.**

More details:

A simple code like this shows that the complexity is linear with respect to the larger dimension:

```
import time
import torch

n = 200
results = []
for m in trange(300, 50000, 500):
    a = torch.rand(n,m)
    start_time = time.time()
    b = torch.pinverse(a)
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    results.append((m, duration))

res = list(zip(*results))
plt.plot(res[0], res[1])
```

[image]

While for values smaller than `n` we have:

```
n = 1100
results = []
for m in trange(50, n, 20):
    a = torch.rand(n,m)
    start_time = time.time()
    b = torch.pinverse(a)
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    results.append((m, duration))
```

[image]